Will fire still burn well in my atmosphere?: concentration vs partial pressure
I recently learned from this article that flammability in oxygenated environments is far more dependent on the concentration of the Oxygen in the air rather than the partial pressure of the Oxygen.
In other words: fires will burn better in air with more Oxygen percentage (relative to the other gases) rather than increasing the pressure of the overall air itself.
With this in mind, I am concerned that fires in the atmosphere of my world will burn really poorly (or not burn at all) because even though I have a high partial pressure of Oxygen, the concentration is low:

The atmosphere of my world has an overall pressure of 5 atm at sea level.
The partial pressure of Oxygen in my world is 0.35 atm at sea level (this means the concentration is only 7% of the total atmospheric volume).
The rest of the atmosphere is primarily Nitrogen and small amounts of Argon and Carbon Dioxide.

Will fire burn poorly in my atmosphere, or will it still burn well? How will it behave?

No fundamental issue with the question as worldbuilding, but you may get better/faster answer on Chemistry SE.  Just strip out the worldbuilding and go with "In an atmospheric mixture of X, Y and Z by percentage at a pressure of 5 atm, would combustion of [example substance] occur faster or slower than in a standard 1 atm Earth-normal atmosphere"

I might be wrong, but isn't 0.35atm even better as on earth with only 0.21atm? Might even drive reactions to be violent/explosive.

@Antares see my answer - you’d think so, but there’s actually fewer oxygen atoms per nitrogen atoms. Random fuel-oxygen collisions would be less frequent, although air-fuel collisions would happen more often (also consider we’re multiplying the air pressure by 5 and dividing the oxygen concentration by more than 10).

Well, you've had various interpretations of your figures in the answers, and none of them match my interpretation of what I'm reading. Can you clarify exactly what the figures are and relate to.

See my reply to Ash under one of the answers.

Are you imagining humans being the beneficiaries of the fires you want to start?  Because your ~ 35 kPa partial pressure of oxygen would be very bad for humans, well into the range for hyperoxia.

@casualworldbuilder I understand now.

It depends entirely on what you are burning
Hypoxic fire suppression systems exist where the oxygen percentage is lowered to 15%.
Hypoxic fire suppression wikipedia

In a normobaric hypoxic environment, common materials cannot ignite or burn when exposed to a localized small scale ignition source.1 A reduction of the oxygen level to 15% does not achieve conditions where a fire cannot occur or is extinguished. However, it reduces the probability of a fire occurring by increasing the ignition energy needed, and there are also indications of increased ignition times.

The key variable here is the oxidizer used in the reaction. For fires that require atmospheric oxygen, your colonists will probably have a tough time with ignition. My guess is they will not be sitting around a campfire without adding an artificial oxidizer to the mix. Any fire to a carbon fuel will burn slowly and be easily put out.
But there are other types of fires

Some chemicals, such as fluorine gas, perchlorate salts such as ammonium perchlorate, or chlorine trifluoride, act as oxidizers, sometimes more powerful ones than oxygen itself. A fire based on a reaction with these oxidizers can be very difficult to put out until the oxidizer is exhausted; that leg of the fire triangle cannot be broken by normal means (i.e., depriving it of air will not smother it).

Anything that brings its own oxygen or acts as an oxidizer will burn regardless of the atmospheric concentrations.
You would also still be able to achieve internal combustion
We have methods of compressing air to stimulate the fuel mix. So you could have a turbo or supercharged engine on your planet, albeit with a penalty to horsepower. For references here, just look up how we deal with high altitude combustion.

Fire yes, wood no. There are compounds that when combined will burn, period, because one of them is a strong oxidiser and/or produces molecular O2, or even Ozone, as part of the reaction. However wood and other bulk carbon fuels that we're used to likely aren't reactive enough to burn straight up in an atmosphere that loaded with inert gases.

Here is a frame challenge.
You are worried whether combustion can happen in your atmosphere. What is the most important form of combustion for humans?  Oxidation or combustion of various substances in the human body.
Possibly you might worry whether humans can survive in the atmosphere you designed.
You write:

The atmosphere of my world has an overall pressure of 5 atm at sea level.
The partial pressure of Oxygen in my world is 0.35 atm at sea level (this means the concentration is only 7% of the total atmospheric volume).


The rest of the atmosphere is primarily Nitrogen and small amounts of Argon and Carbon Dioxide.

The first comment which comes to mind is that Carbon Dioxide shouldn't be present in small amounts but in very, very small amounts. A little bit of atmospheric carbon dioxide is necessary for plants to produce oxygen, but Carbon Dioxide becomes toxic at very small amounts, so you cannot chose a percentage of Carbon Dioxide in your atmosphere high enough to contribute noticeably to the atmospheric pressure.
If the world has a atmospheric pressure of 5 atmospheres at sea level that would equal 5 atm.

Atmospheric pressure, also known as air pressure or barometric pressure (after the barometer), is the pressure within the atmosphere of Earth. The standard atmosphere (symbol: atm) is a unit of pressure defined as 101,325 Pa (1,013.25 hPa), which is equivalent to 1,013.25 millibars,1 760 mm Hg, 29.9212 inches Hg, or 14.696 psi.2 The atm unit is roughly equivalent to the mean sea-level atmospheric pressure on Earth; that is, the Earth's atmospheric pressure at sea level is approximately 1 atm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure
So the sea level pressure on your world should equal about 3,800 mm Hg (millimeters of mercury).  And think that most human visitors to your world prefer to visit and stay in the high mountains where the pressure is a lot lower than that.
You have chosen to give oxygen a partial pressure of 0.35 atm at sea level on your world, which equals 266 mm Hg.
The atmospheric requirements for humans were discussed by Stephen H. Dole in Habitable Planets for Man (1964).
https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf
On page 15 Dole says that the partial pressure of Oxygen at sea level on Earth is about 149 mm Hg and that many humans could survive breathing air with a partial pressure of Oxygen between about 60 mm Hg and about 400 mm Hg.  Thus the atmosphere of your planet at sea level would be about 1.78 as great as on Earth and would be within human tolerance.
With about 3,800 mm Hg total atmospheric pressure at sea level on your world, and a partial pressure of oxygen of 266 mm Hg, the total partial pressure of other gases in your atmosphere would be about 3,534 mm Hg.  And each of those other gases used to dilute the Oxygen would have to have a partial pressure which was less than the limit of toxicity for that gas.
You specified small amounts of Argon in your world's atmosphere.  The maximum tolerable amount of Argon is listed as 1,220 mm Hg.  So your world could have a total of 1,486 mm Hg of Oxygen and Argon, leaving 2,314 mm Hg of other gases.
The maximum tolerable pressure of Nitrogen is about 2,330 mm Hg.  So the maximum
pressure of a human breathable atmosphere of Nitrogen, Argon, and Oxygen would be 2,330 mm Hg of Nitrogen, 1,220 mm Hg of Argon, and 400 mm Hg of Oxygen - or 3,950 mm Hg in total.
So the total pressure of 3,800 mm Hg which you have chosen for your world is just 150 mmHg less than the approximate maximum tolerable level.  And I expect that a number of individual humans would find a pressure of 3,800 mm Hg intolerable and die in it.
But I guess probably most humans would survive at sea level on your world, even though they would probably prefer to live high in the mountains where the air was much thinner.
What about fire and combustion in such an atmosphere?
I recently read an old science fiction story where two humans visit a world - Calisto, a large moon of Jupiter - where, at least in the story, there was a breathable atmosphere but the oxygen content was so low that it was very hard to start a fire and fires were almost unknown. fire.
https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v10n02_1937-10/page/n41/mode/1up
And I thought that it would rather improbable for humans to be able to breathe where the oxygen pressure was so low that it was very hard to start a fire.
But have I read claims that submarines keep the pressure of oxygen low so that the risk of fire is reduced, and as a side effect smokers have a hard time keeping their cigarettes lit.

I didn’t give exact composition values for Nitrogen, Argon and Carbon Dioxide in my atmosphere because I didn’t think they were that relevant to my question. But since you mentioned it: apart from Nitrogen (which will cause mild Narcosis), the gases are at levels tolerable to human colonists.

I’m a relativist/particle physicist, not a chemist, but I have seen diamonds combust at cryogenic temperatures when exposed to nearly-pure oxygen. As it turns out the carbon-oxygen-to-$\mathrm{CO}_2$ reaction is spontaneous at strangely-high temperatures.
However the concentration of oxygen on Earth is low enough that the reaction doesn’t occur spontaneously, or if it does it occurs very slowly. Citation: carbon-based life exists on our planet. Pure oxygen is extremely reactive with virtually all other chemicals and would burn away our entire biosphere in a planet-spanning conflagration if the nitrogen were to disappear from out atmosphere. That nitrogen and argon and trace xenon are key in keeping combustion from being spontaneous at room temperature.
If you decrease the concentration of oxygen to 33% of what’s on Earth, it’ll be roughly like there’s a fire extinguisher constantly blowing on everything, because that’s functionally what’s happening: cutting 2/3 of the oxygen flow to a flame is generally a good way to put it out, and this is how fire extinguishers work. Nitrogen and argon and what have ye getting in between the oxygen and the fuel (which is precisely what will happen when the oxygen concentration is reduced) will probably put out the flame. Yes, the increased atmospheric pressure would make fuel-oxygen collisions (and air-fuel collisions in general) more frequent, but we’re multiplying the air pressure by 5 while we divide the oxygen concentration by 3.
To compensate you could make your world hotter, making oxygen-fuel collisions more frequent and thus making fires still burn, but I doubt they’d look the same as on Earth (I can’t speak to what they would look like, but the vorticity/viscosity/etc of the air would be different under higher pressure), and if you make the temperature too high, it might get a little toasty for any prospective human explorers.

I could be wrong but I think the OP meant 7% total atmospheric volume is Oxygen.

@Ash Whoops, that’s my bad. Still results in cutting the concentration by a factor of 3, though. I will update my answer, thank you.

@Ash Yes. Earth’s atmospheric volume for example is 21% Oxygen and because Earth’s atmospheric pressure at sea level is 1 atm, this means the partial pressure of Oxygen at sea level is 0.21 atm (if the overall pressure were 2 atm the partial pressure of Oxygen would be 0.42 atm). I think most people understand what I’m conveying in my question but explaining here just to clarify.

I doubt the nitrogen can "get in the way" - in an ideal gas, all the particles move mostly independently like they are flying through vacuum.  What the nitrogen can do is bounce off the heated material and carry away some heat before the reaction becomes self-sustaining.
